# Using sed over SSH to remove text from file using regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, ssh, sed

I am trying to remove text from file using the sed command over SSH. The command is:

```
sed -i -r '/(\#\#Some\ text\ domain\.com\ some\ text)((.*?(\n))+.*?)(\#\#Some\ text\ domain\.com\ some\ text)/d' file
```

In the file there is the following text:

```
##Some text domain.com some text
                <IfModule mod_expires.c>
                ExpiresActive On
                ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
                ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
                ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
                ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
                ExpiresByType image/svg "access 1 month"
                ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
                ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
                ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
                ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
                ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 month"
                ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
                ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access 1 month"
                ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
                ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 month"
                ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
                </IfModule>

               <ifModule mod_headers.c>
                  <filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|svg|js|ico)$">
                    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
                 </filesMatch>
                  <filesMatch ".(x?html?|php)$">
                    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
                 </filesMatch>
                </ifModule>

                <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
                  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-woff
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/truetype
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
                  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
                </IfModule>
                ##Some text domain.com some text
```

I have used the next tool to verify my regular experession:

https://regex101.com/

And confirm that the same works, thus I guess the issue is in the sed command. Any ideas are well appreciated!

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: what version of sed the server is using? gnu-sed?

Comment: Hey, I have checked the sed version using the "sed --version" the output of the same is:
GNU sed version 4.2.1
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
to the extent permitted by law.

GNU sed home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-gnu-utils@gnu.org>.
Be sure to include the word ``sed'' somewhere in the ``Subject:'' field.

Comment: How do you call it over SSH? Do you log in to the server and issue the command interactively?

Comment: Sed doesn't support `.*?` non-greedy matching. That's a Perl extension.

Comment: Also, there is no need to escape `#` or spaces. They aren't special to sed.

Comment: From the question title, it sounds like you are trying to do `ssh user@host sed -i -r 'cmds'`.  Be aware that if you do that, quotes will be removed twice.

Comment: Aren't you trying to do just `sed '/##something/,/##something/ d'`?

Comment: BenjaminW. Yes, I am executing the command directly from the command line and after the whole sed command, I am specifying the file I want to alter. 

`sed -i -r '/regex/d' file`

PesaThe I want to remove the whole text between the following lines:

`##Some text domain.com some text

##Some text domain.com some text`

As well, as the two lines above.

Comment: Then why not use the code I posted in my comment? That will indeed remove everything between those lines, them included: `sed '/a/,/b/ d'`. However, be careful. If there is no line matching the `b` pattern, `sed` will delete all lines for `a` to end.

Comment: @PesaThe Thank you for the update! I have tried this suggestion and the output of the console was correct. It shows that the correct lines, however the file is not edited. Thus, I have added the `-i` before the regex and it works now! Thank you very very much for this!!!

Comment: Glad it works. But be really careful should your file not contain the `/b/` part of the match. As soon as `sed` finds the `/a/` part, it will start deleting. And it will stop deleting when it finds `/b/`. So if there is no `/b/` in your file, it will just continue deleting!

Comment: @PesaThe Thank you for the heads up! Actually, I am developing a plugin which will input those rules in the .htaccess file, so it is automated process and there is no chance `/b/` to be missing. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote a working PCRE/Perl compliant expression, use it with `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -i 's/(\#\#Some\ text\ domain\.com\ some\ text)((.*?(\n))+.*?)(\#\#Some\ text\ domain\.com\ some\ text)//g' file
```

That is, `-0777` will slurp the file into a single text where line feeds can be matched with the regex pattern, `-i` will make changes inline, the `s` in `s/` means *substitution*, the pattern is your working pattern from regex101.com, and the replacement pattern is empty. `g` means replace all occurrences.